# Nodejs FsSystem

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

how do i export and use values ​​returned from the date of this function ?

```js
exports.dadosXml = function(){
  
  fs.readFile("./auth/socket_config.json" , "utf8", function(err, data){
    if(data){

      jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
      return  console.log(jsonData);
      
    }else if(err){
      
      return console.log("Erro");
      
    }
    
  });

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback.

```
exports.dadosXml = function(callback){

  fs.readFile("./auth/socket_config.json" , "utf8", function(err, data){
    if(data){
      jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
      return  console.log(jsonData);

    }else if(err){
      return console.log("Erro");
    }
  });
}

dadosXml(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

You can use readFileSync but when this action works it blocks others.

```
exports.dadosXml = function(){
  return fs.readFileSync("./auth/socket_config.json" , "utf8");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the signature of `dadosXml` so that it would take a [callback](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/) function as an argument:

```
exports.dadosXml = function(callback) {
  fs.readFile('./auth/socket_config.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (data) {
      jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
      callback(null, jsonData)
    } else if (err) {
      callback(err)
    }
  });
};
```

Then, in the module that invokes `dadosXml` you need to pass a callback function that will work with the data:

```
dadosXml(function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Data was read successfully', data);
  }
});
```